# logger statement timestamp when there is significant IO delay

Tags: java, logging, log4j, slf4j, java.util.logging

We know, in any Java logging frameworks, we are getting the timestamp of the logger statement is getting printed in the log file in-front the statement. I want to understand what time is derived and getting logged , whether the time is - the log statement in written into the log file , or it is the time when the log statement is executed in the JVM. If there is any delay in IO then we could see variation between these timestamp. Is there any configuration available in Log4j/Slf4j to set this?

Answer (score 2):

When you call one of the `Logger` log methods a `LoggingEvent` is created.  According to the [source code](https://github.com/apache/log4j/blob/trunk/src/main/java/org/apache/log4j/spi/LoggingEvent.java), the timestamp of a `LoggingEvent` is set when the event is created.  That timestamp is what appears in the formatted log messages.

I/O delays in the logging backend should not affect the timestamps.